# React | Can´t load Images > Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem in react, I can´t display my local pictures when the URL is stored in a variable, in my case i´m using the Array.Map function.

So the thing is I want to build a webapp to manage products, for every product there is a picture so I can´t import every single picture by myself.

So a product object looks like this:

```
products: {
 name: "Beer",
 beschreibung: "Gutes Bier",
 preis: 4,
 imgUrl: "./pics/Beer.png",
},
```

In my "Product.js" I mapping throw the product objects:

```
products.map(function (e, i) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <p>{e.name}</p>
         ...
        <img src="..."></img>
    </div>
```

so and here im trying several things:

```
//this works fine:
<img className="img" alt="hallo" src={require("./pics/Beer.png")} />


//this don´t work:
<img className="img" alt="hallo" src={require( `${e.imgUrl}` )} />
```

I checked the correct path so it is not a wrong URL.
My project tree in /src is like this:

```
 -src
   -components
      #App.js
   -style
      #Style.css
   -data
      #Products.json   // There are my test-products saved
  -images
      #img1.jpg
      #img2.jpg
      ...
```

i figured out that when i place files direct inside the /src folder except the images folder then the map.function works fine, so i realy don´t know what to do here.

Comment: `require("./pics/Beer.png")` works because Webpack can figure out what image you are interested in at build time. You can't keep a value like `./pics/Beer.png` in a variable at runtime and use that, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `require()` the images directly in the products data?

```
products: {
 name: "Beer",
 beschreibung: "Gutes Bier",
 preis: 4,
 imgUrl: require("./pics/Beer.png"),
}
```

Assuming you're bundling your product data with everything else, do that for every `imgUrl` and it should work fine. Your other option is to use something like the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy your static files over and reference them with a normal, relative path URL.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to pass the image as prop or use it in different places, you can store it in a variable(rather than rewriting require statement) and use it every where. 
If you are bundeling your modules using webpack. Because `Beer.png` is not a valid javascript module. Webpack will do the trick for you.

ES6 syntax

```
import beerImage from './pics/Beer.png'; //webpack handles it no need of transpiling
```

ES5 syntax

```
var beerImage = require("./pics/Beer.png")

products: {
 name: "Beer",
 beschreibung: "Gutes Bier",
 preis: 4,
 imgUrl: beerImage,
}
```